# Typescript - generic return type based on the type of the generic type property

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function to create and render react components dynamically, in order to obtain a value through a callback

I defined the following interfaces

```
type InvocableDialogProps<R = never> = {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: (r: R) => void;
};

//Cannot find name 'R'.
type Opendialog<P extends InvocableDialogProps<R>> = (
  Dialog: FunctionComponent<P>,
  props: P
) => Promise<R>;

const openDialog: Opendialog = (dialog, props) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    createElement(dialog, {
      ...props,
      onClose: result => {
        resolve(result);
      },
    });
  });
};

type DialogProps = InvocableDialogProps<boolean>;

const Dialog: FunctionComponent<DialogProps> = ({ onClose }) => {
  ...
}

const result = await openDialog(Dialog, { open: true });
```

How can I infer that the type of the returned value is boolean, that is, it depends on the generic type of `DialogProps`

this is a sandbox of my code https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-goldstine-cyirpr

the current problem is the correct definition of types

Comment: I don't think this is going to work...at the point where you did `await openDialog(...)`, everything will start waiting for the promise to resolve, so the element will never be rendered, talkless of the `onClose` callback being invoked. Also prefer, `cloneElement` to `createElement`, unless you have good reason not to

Comment: @smac89 If this is top-level await, sure, but it's probably more likely that this is going to be used in some async closure.

Comment: @caTS It doesn't matter where it is called, at some point the `openDialog(...)` will be called, but will never resolve. The only hope is to use `ReactDOM.render(...)` (or `ReactDOM.createRoot(...).render(...)` in react 18) to render the component in a different part of the DOM.

Comment: @smac89 I don't think so: https://tsplay.dev/WJX6gN

Comment: @caTS Try that in a react context. It is afterall react which will render the component that exposes the `onClose` callback. Also your code does not wait for the promise to resolve, which kinda proves my point

Comment: @smac89 `openDialog` is a function inside a context where I render the new component.
`const component = createElement(.., { onClose })`
`setDialog(component)`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to infer only `R` generic. Consider this:

```js
import { FC, createElement } from 'react'

type InvocableDialogProps<R> = {
    open: boolean;
    onClose: (r: R) => void;
};


const openDialog = <R,>(dialog: FC<InvocableDialogProps<R>>, props: InvocableDialogProps<R>) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        createElement(dialog, {
            ...props,
            onClose: result => {
                resolve(result);
            },
        });
    });
};

type DialogProps = InvocableDialogProps<boolean>;

const Dialog: FC<DialogProps> = ({ onClose }) => {
    return null
}

const result = await openDialog(Dialog, {
    open: true, onClose: (bool) => {
        bool // boolean
    }
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOA6dm)

Comment: I think OP wants to Omit `onClose` since it'll be provided in the promise.

Comment: @Gustavo Perez Machado do you want to omit onClose?

Comment: in this way it does not infer the extra properties of the `Dialog` component